# G++ does not seem to recognize -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I compile my code with the flag `-std=c++11` given, and I get all kinds of errors depicting that I should use the same flag. Also, `auto` is not recognised being a type.

Makefile:

```
GCCPATH = /path/gcc/5.3.0
CC = $(GCCPATH)/bin/g++
DARGS = -ggdb               #debug arguments
CARGS = -std=c++11          #C arguments
WARGS = -Wall -Wextra       #warning arguments
AARGS = $(DARGS) $(CARGS) $(WARGS)  #all arguments
GCCLIBPATH = $(GCCPATH)/lib64
LIBS = -l curl
LIBD = -L $(GCCLIBPATH) -Wl,-rpath=$(GCCLIBPATH)

.PHONY: webspider

webspider: ../title/htmlstreamparser.o filesystem.o
    $(CC) $(AARGS) -o $@ $@.cpp $+ $(LIBS) $(LIBD)

filesystem:
    $(CC) $(AARGS) -c $@.cpp
```

The warnings and errors I get:

```
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
warning: range-based ‘for’ loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
error: ‘weblink’ does not name a type
  for(auto weblink: weblinks)
```

Now my question is: What should I do to make g++ recognise this clearly given flag?
I also tried to replace it with `-std=c++0x`, to no avail.

EDIT:
Full output of `make`:

```
g++    -c -o filesystem.o filesystem.cpp
In file included from filesystem.cpp:1:0:
filesystem.hpp:23:36: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   std::string dir = getCurrentPath();
                                    ^
filesystem.cpp: In member function ‘std::__cxx11::string Filesystem::createMD5(std::__cxx11::string)’:
filesystem.cpp:49:19: warning: range-based ‘for’ loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
  for(long long c: result)
                   ^
filesystem.cpp: In member function ‘void Filesystem::createLinkIndex(std::__cxx11::string, strVec)’:
filesystem.cpp:57:11: error: ‘weblink’ does not name a type
  for(auto weblink: weblinks) {
           ^
filesystem.cpp:61:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
filesystem.cpp:61:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
filesystem.cpp:61:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
filesystem.cpp:61:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
filesystem.cpp:61:1: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘}’ token
filesystem.cpp:61:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
make: *** [filesystem.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11`?

Comment: Do you see if the flag is passed to gcc and just not recognized or if its actually a problem with the makefile?

Comment: @NathanOliver That was what I was going to say...

Comment: Can you copy and paste the actual commands emitted by your makefile into the question ?

Comment: can you `make VERBOSE=1` and verify the options passed to gcc are the right ones?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see the full console output.

Comment: @NathanOliver Names of variables in a Makefile matter?

Comment: The `Makefile` you posted works for me, it adds the flag

Comment: Based on the output you just gave us, the `-std=c++11` flag is never added to your `g++` call.

Comment: If your build relies on *implicit* commands then yes the names **do** matter. Try setting `CXXFLAGS` instead.

Comment: @SimonKlaver Not 100% sure.  I don't use makefiles.  This is just how I have seen it on most/all the makefiles I have seen on here.

Comment: You're hiding something from us or you do not use GNUMake. I've tried your makefile, it works like a charm.

Comment: Something very fishy here - either that's not the right makefile, or you have more than one (either in different directories or with different names).

Comment: `filesystem: ...` -- Your rule isn't creating `filesystem`, it's creating `filesystem.o`, and you should specify that properly in the target so that make knows to execute that rule when it looks for how to create `filesystem.o`. I don't see how the Makefile would work for the other commenters. Voting to close as a typo not since it's a bad question, but because it's not likely to be useful to others.

Comment: I think that this question is valid for others that are learning to work with makefiles and shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @PaulR `htmlstreamparser.o` is precompiled, and therefore not made in this Makefile ;). Aside from that there is nothing really strange (`path` should be clear to be no real path) AFAICT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you do not specify all your dependencies, in particular how to build all your intermediate *object files*.

So what happens is `make` makes up its own rules and invisibly sneaks them in while you're not looking.

The way to control these [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) is through setting the correct [predefined variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables):

```
CXX := $(GCCPATH)/bin/g++      # c++ compiler
CPPFLAGS := -I/path/to/headers # preprocessor flags
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11         # compiler flags
LDFLAGS := -L/path/to/libs     # linker flags
LDLIBS := -lcurl               # libraries to link
# etc...
```

By using the correct *predefined variables*, rather than making up your own, you can save a lot of work when building a `Makefile`.

Comment: Accepted not because it was the answer that helped me most, but because it is the answer that will help people in general most.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, based on the comments, it was fixed by changing

```
filesystem:
    $(CC) $(AARGS) -c $@.cpp
```

to

```
filesystem.o: filesystem.cpp
    $(CC) $(AARGS) -c $+
```

as Makefile did not understand that I was trying to make `filesystem.o` with the rule `filesystem: ...`. When stating this explicitely, it worked as intended.

Advantage of this method over the answer of Galik is the ability to use own variables, albeit in this case not that much of an advantage since it is a small project.