# g++ -std=c++11, flag not taking effect

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, g++, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to change the version of c++ dialect to c++11 and the flag seems to not take affect.

Here is snippet from my makefile:

```
#Path Definitions
PATHT = test/
PATHI = inc/
PATHB = build/
PATHS = src/

#Files of interest
CODER_C   = $(PATHS)E8b9b.cpp
CODER_O   = $(PATHB)E8b9b.o
CODER_H   = $(PATHI)E8b9b.hpp
CODER_C_T = $(PATHT)Test_E8b9b_encoder.cpp
CODER_O_T = $(PATHB)Test_E8b9b_encoder.o
TRAN_C    = $(PATHS)TransactionID.cpp
TRAN_O    = $(PATHB)TransactionID.o
TRAN_H    = $(PATHI)TransactionID.hpp
TRAN_C_T  = $(PATHT)Test_TransactionID.cpp
TRAN_O_T  = $(PATHB)Test_TransactionID.o
SIGV_C    = $(PATHS)SigView.cpp
SIGV_O    = $(PATHB)SigView.o
SIGV_H    = $(PATHI)SigView.hpp
SIGV_C_T  = $(PATHT)Test_SigView.cpp
SIGV_O_T  = $(PATHB)Test_SigView.o
TESOUT    = $(PATHB)Test.out
RUNOUT    = $(PATHB)Run.out

#Libraries of interest
BOOSTL = -lboost_unit_test_framework 
INCH   = -Iinc 

#Tool Definitions 
CC=g++
FLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall

test: $(CODER_O_T) $(CODER_O) $(TRAN_O_T) $(TRAN_O) $(SIGV_O_T) $(SIGV_O)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(CODER_O_T) $(CODER_O) $(TRAN_O_T) $(TRAN_O) $(SIGV_O_T) $(SIGV_O) $(BOOSTL)  \
    -o $(TESOUT) 2> buildLog.txt
    ./$(TESOUT) 1> buildLog.txt

$(CODER_O_T): $(CODER_C_T) $(CODER_H)  
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(INCH) -c $< -o $@ 2> buildLog.txt

$(CODER_O): $(CODER_C) $(CODER_H)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(INCH) -c $< -o $@ 2> buildLog.txt 

$(TRAN_O_T): $(TRAN_C_T) $(TRAN_H)  
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(INCH) -c $< -o $@ 2> buildLog.txt

$(TRAN_O): $(TRAN_C) $(TRAN_H)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(INCH) -c $< -o $@ 2> buildLog.txt

$(SIGV_O_T): $(SIGV_C_T) $(SIGV_H)  
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(INCH) -c $< -o $@ 2> buildLog.txt

$(SIGV_O): $(SIGV_C) $(SIGV_H)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(INCH) -c $< -o $@ 2> buildLog.txt
```

I am checking the dialect with the following unit test:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "SigView.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h> // For the __cplusplus define 

/*
These are the C++ standards and what value you should be able to expect in __cplusplus:
C++ pre-C++98: __cplusplus is 1.
C++98: __cplusplus is 199711L.
C++98 + TR1: This reads as C++98 and there is no way to check that I know of.
C++11: __cplusplus is 201103L.
C++14: __cplusplus is 201402L.
*/

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(RandomSystemTest)
{
    BOOST_TEST_REQUIRE(__cplusplus == 201103L, "c++ dialect is " << __cplusplus);
}
```

The test case fails and outputs the following:

```
fatal error: in "RandomSystemTest": c++ v is 199711
```

the version still states 199711.

I have tried multiple flags which have not made a difference:

```
c11
c++11
c++0x
gnu++11
```

Version of g++ = 4.8.4
Ubuntu version 14.04.4 LTS

Edit:

As requested the output of the make:

```
$ make test
g++ --std=c++11 -Wall -Iinc  -c test/Test_SigView.cpp -o build/Test_SigView.o 2> buildLog.txt
g++ --std=c++11 -Wall build/Test_E8b9b_encoder.o build/E8b9b.o build/Test_TransactionID.o build/TransactionID.o build/Test_SigView.o build/SigView.o -lboost_unit_test_framework   \
    -o build/Test.out 2> buildLog.txt
./build/Test.out 
Running 11 test cases...

*** No errors detected
```

And now it works! I have no idea why. The only difference I did was to execute g++ -std=c++11 -dM -E -xc++ /dev/null | grep __cplusplus as suggested by @Dietrich Epp

Comment: I don't see a definition for `$(A_OBJECT)` or `$(A_CFILE)` anywhere.  Is there a reason you're not just using `%.o: %.cpp` or something similar?

Comment: I left out the definitions to simplify, otherwise I have every file in the project defined and added in line to each g++ call. As of right now I do not understand how %.o: and %.cpp works to be able to use them.

Comment: Perhaps you might show us the listing of the compile and link.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase that.  Show us the definition of `$(A_OBJECT)` and `$(A_CFILE)` or else we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @DietrichEpp  I have added the complete makefile

Comment: This may be related to (and therefore a duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726365/g-does-not-seem-to-recognize-std-c11/35726788#35726788 if it turns out you have some explicit rules being run that you didn't allow for.

Comment: What commands is make executing?  Could you run the command `g++ -std=c++11 -dM -E -xc++ /dev/null | grep __cplusplus`?

Comment: @DietrichEpp output is = #define __cplusplus 201103L. So the correct version is set?

Comment: Can you post the actual `make` output?

Comment: off topic: "effect", not "affect"

Comment: @Volcano: It sounds like it is a problem with your makefile, then.  Make will print out each command as it is run, make sure that it's actually running the command you want.  Sometimes if there's an error you will end up using default rules instead of the rules you define (which is one of the reasons I use Ninja these days).

Comment: Probably what happened here is you built the object files incorrectly, and then changed the makefile.  The object files didn't get rebuilt.  (Another reason why I use Ninja these days.)

Comment: @DietrichEpp I understand, thank you.

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that both --std=c+11 and -std=c++11 work

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your Makefile it seems your linking order is wrong. Put the -std=c++11 after your source code file. One best practice I learned was to always put your source .cpp files first, right after g++.

Comment: This shouldn't have any effect. Only linker flags are affected by order, as far as I know.